# Alinhando campos com inline-forms do bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, front-end, visual-studio-2017

Boa tarde!

Não tenho muita experiência com frontend, mas vou ter que me virar pra terminar um projeto, por isso vou precisar de uma ajudinha.

Minha dúvida é, tenho alguns forms na tela, e gostaria que ele ficasse alinhandos um em baixo do outro, mas não to conseguindo de jeito nenhum.

Como podem ver, velocidade e resumo eu não consigo alinhar, além de tb não conseguir padronizar o tamanho dos campos.

Estou usando o css 3 que o scaffolding do visual studio usa

[image: Imagem forms]

```
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })

                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.SapId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.SapId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.SapId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeAgua, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-10" })
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeAgua, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeAgua, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeOleo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
        <div class="col-md-11">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeOleo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeOleo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.Velocidade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.Velocidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.Velocidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.Resumo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-6" })
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.Resumo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.Resumo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.Setor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.Setor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.Setor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Voltar

Comment: Cara vc tem que colocar col-md-12 em TUDO. Qualquer classe que estiver com col-md-XX vc deve substituir o número por 12 ficando todas as classes com col-md-12, isso pode te ajudar, pois vendo por alto parece sem sentido a forma como vc usou os valores dessas colunas do grid..., mas como quer tudo em uma coluna só usando col-md-12 deve resolver...

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela ajuda.
Foi como eu disse, só faço backend, to fazendo o front, pq não tem ninguem .
Mas aproveitando a oportunidade, qual foi o sentido em colocar as colunas em 12? sei q tem a divisão que o bootstrap faz, mas nunca consegui entender direito

Comment: Aqui tem a documentação oficial do Grid do Bootstrap. É bem fácil de entender, vale a pena parar 5 min para ler https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ vc vai ver que por exemplo duas divs com a classe  col-md-6 vão gerar duas colunas iguais com largura de 50% cada. Já duas colunas com  col-md-12, vai gerar apenas uma coluna, com cada div ocupando 100% da largura.

Answer (score -1):

Se você quer que cada input tenha o mesmo tamanho e alinhamento um abaixo do outro com 3 input por linha você tem que definir para cada `form-group` 3 `div` com classe `col-md-4`, cada linha do seu form por padrão tem o tamanho de col-md-12 ... ***(12)*** é equivalente a 12 colunas de uma tabela. quando você criar uma div que tem `col-md-4` ela ocupara 4 colunas do seu pai.

O código abaixo deixa a linha com 3 colunas.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.SapId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.SapId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.SapId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeAgua, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeAgua, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeAgua, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Mas se você pretende por uma coluna por linha use.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Para cada linha.

Comment: Opa, obrigado!

Respondei como uma resposta, para pode postar as imagens de como ficou.

Comment: @Janson, se a resposta resolveu seu problema basta aceita como resposta correta.